# align input and select in same line (bootstrap mobile)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to align input and select in same line , below code works in desktop but in mobile ,select list is coming down to new line even though I used `col-sm`.

Below is the form code

```
<form class="form-horizontal">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="name" type="text">
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-5">
     <select class="form-control" name="category">
        <option>select</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>

</form>
```

And here is bootply http://www.bootply.com/9N0DxgUSMi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding col-xs-5, and for example col-xs-12 to your password label? Should work :)